# Error when trying to predict with new data in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I got a dataset composed of 432 batches of 24 points each one of them. Shape of the entire dataset: (432, 24)

To put an example, this would be one batch:

```
array([917,  15, 829,  87, 693,  71, 627, 359, 770, 303, 667, 367, 754,
       359, 532,  39, 683, 407, 333, 551, 516,  31, 675,  39])
```

with shape (24,)

I am feeding a Keras model with this info. No issues.
When I try to predict with new data with the same shape (24,):

```
array([176,  71, 152,  63, 200,  71, 120,  87, 128,  87, 216, 103, 248,
       126, 144, 150, 128, 206, 192, 206, 112, 277, 216, 269])
```

My model:

```
  model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(batch_input_shape=(None,24)),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),

        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
    ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The error raised:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_24 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 24 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your code where you actually call the model to predict your data. Without this nobody can help.

Comment: Note that if you use categorical cross-entropy loss, you must use the activation function tf.nn.softmax instead of tf.nn.sigmoid in the last layer of the model.
Alternatively, you can put no activation function in the last layer and use loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) in model.compile().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding a dimension to your data sample and then feed your `new_data` into your model to make a prediction:

```py
import numpy as np


new_data= np.array([176,  71, 152,  63, 200,  71, 120,  87, 128,  87, 216, 103, 248,
       126, 144, 150, 128, 206, 192, 206, 112, 277, 216, 269])

new_data= np.expand_dims(new_data, axis=0)

prediction = model.predict(new_data)
print(prediction)
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as Keras requires a 3D array to be fed into the input